# No Synchronization in the Eclipse Navigator Window for the Neon Release

Tags: eclipse, macos

Before I switched to this release the Eclipse Navigator had nice feature.  Clicking on the file tab in the right pane rearranges the Navigator, so the node corresponding to this file in the Navigator becomes visible and highlighted.  I do not see this feature anymore. I am on macosx.

For some reason the Mars and Neon (even 4.6.2) new workspaces I created do not have this feature. But my old workspace in Mars does. So I am thinking that maybe something is not working in my new workspaces.

Comment: It is still there on my Eclipse 4.6.2 on macOS.

Comment: Not working for me with Neon.  Mars works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called 'Link with Editor' and has to be turned on. Click the two way arrow at the top right of the view to enable it. When enabled the arrow looks 'depressed':

[image: Enabled Link to Editor]